# PHP: How to get current memcached object persistence id

Tags: php, memcached

> Is there any way to get current memcached instance persistence id in
>   PHP?

---

```
// Some place in code     
$persistence = 'my servername_' . md5(unique()); 
$memcachedObject = new Memcached($persistence);
```

And then somewhere else something like:

```
$memcachedObject->getPersistenceId();
```

Comment: The point of using a persistent connection to share the connection with a known id which you have `$persistence` so if you want to know the id later in your script you simply reference `$persistence`

Comment: What if a process is forked or other complicated situations?